# Stopwatch in java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to design an online exam website for 4 subjects at a time by adding 4 aspx pages to a Master page. For that I need to have an stopwatch.

With my knowledge, I had designed an stopwatch in JavaScript and attached it to master page.

```
var tim;
var min = 120;
var sec = 60;
var f = new Date();

function f1() {
    f2();
    document.getElementById("startday").innerHTML = f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + f.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("starttime").innerHTML = "Exam Starts at " + f.getHours() + ":" + f.getMinutes();
    //document.getElementById("endtime").innerHTML = "Your  time is :" + f.toLocaleTimeString();
}

function f2() {
    if (parseInt(sec) > 0) {
        sec = parseInt(sec) - 1;
        document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
        tim = setTimeout("f2()", 1000);
    } else {
        if (parseInt(sec) == 0) {
            min = parseInt(min) - 1;
            if (parseInt(min) == 0) {
                clearTimeout(tim);
                location.href = "default5.aspx";
            } else {
                sec = 60;
                document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
                tim = setTimeout("f2()", 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my problem is that if I am changing my subject, that master page is also getting refresh and stop watch time is starting again from 120 min onward.

So please help me. Even though I change the subject, the time should continue as it is without any refresh.

Comment: Little reminder: doing `parseInt(sec)` *will* give you headaches later. Instead, do this: `+sec` or `parseFloat(sec)` or `parseInt(sec, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in ASP, you should keep the timer on the server side and introduce it into the newly loaded pages (so that you retain state as you go).  Otherwise, you could set cookies and pick up where you left off as you go from page to page.

Alternatively, you could load the new pages dynamically, so that you never leave the main page (in which the timer resides) either using iframes or, if all the pages are local to one domain, you can load them via ajax.

But I do think that the first option is the best, if you have control over the ASP.

Comment: If you're asking this question you need to become more familiar with both the client and the server technologies involved here. ASP generates HTML pages (amongst other things). When they're generated they behave like any other HTML pages, which includes iframes and anything else that HTML has to offer). @namkha87's answer is what I'm describing as the ideal solution. Only use iframes if you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ASP.Net Web Form. You can use Session to keep the state of Clock. In master page, you can have something like that

```
<script>
    var min = <%= Session["min"] %>;
    var sec = <%= Session["sec"] %>;
</script>
```

Everytime user switch to another page, try to update the Session state.